# L2E for insert, update, delete

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using .Net3.5. Just wondering my understanding about the insert, update, delete are correct when use L2E.

For insert, we need two statements:

```
context.AddObject("entityName", newRow);
context.SaveChanges();
```

For update, we only need one statement:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

For delete, we need two statements:

```
context.DeleteObject(deletedRow);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing an update you first need to update a property of an entity of course.

Your code for insert and delete is correct.

But what is your question actually?